# Decision Tree not classifying 3 categories variable

Tags: r

I'm trying to building a decision tree with a categorical variable (3 categories), with 194 predictors.

The data is from an e-commerce and the goal is to know if the customer has only girls, only boys or both gender children based on the products they bought. 
The problem is that the decision tree is only returning 2 classifications (boys and girls and none condition is classified as both genders).

This is my R code:

```
fit <- rpart(GENDER~X1+X2+X3+X4+...+X193+X194,method="class", data=data)
```

These are my results:

```
n= 4179 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

 1) root 4179 2184 girl (0.12921752 0.47738693 0.39339555)  
   2) X120>=0.5 1042  229 girl(0.16890595 0.78023033 0.05086372) *
   3) X120< 0.5 3137 1546 boy(0.11603443 0.37679311 0.50717246)  
     6) X109>=0.5 381  120 girl(0.19160105 0.68503937 0.12335958) *
     7) X109< 0.5 2756 1212 boy(0.10558781 0.33417997 0.56023222)  
      14) X194>=0.5 129   34 girl(0.20155039 0.73643411 0.06201550) *
      15) X194< 0.5 2627 1091 boy(0.10087552 0.31442710 0.58469737)  
        30) X119< 0.5 2382 1057 boy(0.10327456 0.34047019 0.55625525)  
          60) X122>=0.5 70   12 girl (0.12857143 0.82857143 0.04285714) *
          61) X122< 0.5 2312  990 boy(0.10250865 0.32569204 0.57179931) *
        31) X119>=0.5 245   34 boy(0.07755102 0.06122449 0.86122449) *

Classification tree:
rpart(formula = GENDER ~ ., data = crs$dataset[crs$train, c(crs$input, 
    crs$target)], method = "class", parms = list(split = "information"), 
    control = rpart.control(usesurrogate = 0, maxsurrogate = 0))
```

How can I classify in the 3 categories instead of just 2?

Comment: How many occurrences of "both" do you have in the training data? It's possible that they are so few that they don't make a big difference in the error measure of the tree classifier. Use `randomForest` to grow more trees and combine them.

Comment: Or just so few that they are never the plurality choice in any leaf.

Comment: @ilir total dataset is 5971 lines, girls = 2844, boys = 2359, both = 768

Comment: @Spacedman I'm sorry, my data is in portuguese, so actually "Girl" is "Menina" in the original dataset. I just translated it for english in the question for others understand and help me without stupid questions like yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `rpart()` has some stopping rules that prevent it fitting the full tree (i.e. a single observation in each node) because this is rarely what you want and you'll just end up pruning these bushy, redundant leaves back.

Hence I would suggest that your tree is not capable of predicting the class `Both` as, as far as the built tree is concerned was never the majority vote winner in any of the terminal nodes.  The three values in parentheses after the `girl` or `boy` are the posterior probabilities of each class. `boy` is the 2nd value, `girl` the third value, and `both` the first value (given that this would be the default way R assigned the order of the levels). So `rpart()` is taking into account the fact that there are three classes, it's just that the split it identified never predicted that class `both`.

You could force `rpart` to build a large/full tree; look at `?rpart.control` and the arguments `minsplit`, `minbucket` and `cp` which all act to stop the tree growing too large, but are set up for somewhat largish problems. You can adjust these to fit a full tree (set them all low), but be aware that you'll probably end up pruning back most of these outer leaves.

As to why randomForest gives back the third category; perhaps there are bootstrap samples where you are able to predict the class `both()`, or there are variables important for the prediction of `both` which are highlighted because randomForest draws `mtry` variables at random to test when choosing each split.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran a random forest with the same dataset and the third category appeared.

Comment: The Third category was there in the `rpart()` output you show it's just that none of the nodes had the higher posterior probability (or majority vote) for the `both` class.