# I am having 3 classification, but my decision tree shows only 2

Tags: r, decision-tree, supervised-learning

```
library(caret)
library(rpart.plot)
car_df <- read.csv("E:/SMM/TrainingDataSet (3).csv", sep = ',', header = 
TRUE)
str(car_df)

with(car_df, table( Result))



set.seed(3033)
intrain <- createDataPartition(y = car_df$Result, p= 0.7, list = FALSE)
training <- car_df[intrain,]
testing <- car_df[-intrain,]
dim(training)
dim(testing)
anyNA(car_df)
trctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 3, repeats = 2)
set.seed(3333)
dtree_fit <- train(Result ~., data = training, method = "rpart",
               parms = list(split = "gini"),
               trControl=trctrl,
               tuneLength = 10)
with(testing, table( Result))
dtree_fit

prp(dtree_fit$finalModel, box.palette = "Reds", tweak = 1.2)
testing[1,]

predict(dtree_fit, newdata = testing[1,])
test_pred <- predict(dtree_fit, newdata = testing)
confusionMatrix(test_pred, testing$Result )
```

[image: CLASSIFICATION TREE]

Basically, I am trying to classify the movies based on the positive negative and neutral tweets. I have a dataset of 42 movies with 14 flops, 13 hits, 15 average movies.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540999/decision-tree-not-classifying-3-categories-variable

Comment: Thank you! But a clear solution was not provided. Can you help? @MrFlick